# Storing dynamic URL in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, regex, next.js

I am working on a Next.js project with authentication and am putting some URLs as strings into an array called protectedRoutes, so people get redirected when they access those URLs before they sign in.

```
const protectedRoutes = ["/home", "/profile", etc.];
```

I also got some posts to display in my project where each post will have its own page.
Each post has a unique id stored in firebase and I had set up the router query already in Next.js.

Let say I have a post.id == "BjPDBvsWIsa11l6JxFOAgzR3mnG3" so its URL would be /post/BjPDBvsWIsa11l6JxFOAgzR3mnG3.

My question is, how do I store each post's URL into the protectedRoutes array? Is there a way I can do this with Regex?

Thank you very much.

```
const postURL = new RegExp("/post/")
const protectedRoutes = ["/home", "/profile", postURL];
```

is not working.

Edit 29/3:

I also wish to avoid the following:

```
const postID = getPostID() // function that fetches post IDs from firebase

postID.forEach((id) => {
  protectedRoutes.push(`/post/${id}`);
});
```

so to avoid making a long array once the number of posts grows, which slows down the search.

Edit 30/3:

Below shows the file containing protectedRoutes and the component that handles redirection.

In my _app.js,

```
import PrivateRoute from "@/components/PrivateRoute";
import { AuthProvider } from "@/contexts/AuthContext";
import "@/styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const protectedRoutes = ["/home", "/profile"];
  const publicRoutes = [
    "/",
    "/sign-in",
    "/sign-in/phone",
    "/sign-up",
    "/reset-password",
  ];

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <PrivateRoute
        protectedRoutes={protectedRoutes}
        publicRoutes={publicRoutes}
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PrivateRoute>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

and in my PrivateRoute.jsx,

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import { useAuth } from "@/contexts/AuthContext";
import FullPageLoader from "./FullPageLoader";

export default function PrivateRoute({
  protectedRoutes,
  publicRoutes,
  children,
}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { currentUser, loading } = useAuth();

  const pathIsProtected = protectedRoutes.indexOf(router.pathname) !== -1;
  const pathIsPublic = publicRoutes.indexOf(router.pathname) !== -1;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !currentUser && pathIsProtected) {
      router.push("/sign-in");
    }

    if (!loading && currentUser && pathIsPublic) {
      router.push("/home");
    }
  }, [currentUser, loading, pathIsProtected, pathIsPublic]);

  if ((loading || !currentUser) && pathIsProtected) {
    return <FullPageLoader />;
  }

  if ((loading || currentUser) && pathIsPublic) {
    return <FullPageLoader />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

Comment: Where is this array evaluated? In other words: Where is the redirection to the sign-in page implemented?

Comment: The array is passed to another component that wraps the  <Component {...pageProps} /> and does the redirection job. @HeikoTheißen

Comment: How you use `protectedRoutes` at somewhere? Which Router you used? React-Router? Which environment did those code run in?Please provide more info.

Comment: Please see edit on 30/3 @Mee

Answer (score 0):

Test follow code,

```
  const url1 = '/post/dadsa'
  const url2 = '/post/sdadasdas/dadsa'
  const url3 = '/postsdadasdas/dadsa'
  const url4 = '/'
  const url5 = ''

  const getRealPath = (url) => url.split('/').filter(v=>v!=='')[0] ? '/' + url.split('/').filter(v=>v!=='')[0] : url

  console.log(getRealPath(url1))
  console.log(getRealPath(url2))
  console.log(getRealPath(url3))
  console.log(getRealPath(url4))
  console.log(getRealPath(url5))
```

Edit your app.js,

```
  const protectedRoutes = ["/home", "/profile", "/post"];
```

Edit your PrivateRoute.jsx,

```
+ const getRealPath = (url) => url.split('/').filter(v=>v!=='')[0] ? '/' + url.split('/').filter(v=>v!=='')[0] : url

- const pathIsProtected = protectedRoutes.indexOf(router.pathname) !== -1;
+ const pathIsProtected = protectedRoutes.indexOf(getRealPath(router.pathname)) !== -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const protectedRoutes = ["/home", "/profile", etc.];

// Create \/home|\/profile|etc.
const strRegProtected = protectedRoutes.join('|').replace(/\//g, '\\/')

// Create /^(\/home|\/profile|etc.)/
const regProtected = RegExp(`^(${strRegProtected})`)

const isUrlProtected = regProtected.test('/home/85948')
```